Re-scale effect size region in Metafor forest plot
Im trying to create a forest plot of Mean Difference in the style of Revman, using Metafor in R I have encountered the problem that the pooled estimate overlaps with the RoB section, is there any way of **re-scaling or restricting the Estimate region **so it is all contained withing that area of the graph, in order to keep my RoB region unaltered ? (I have used argument alim but it doesnt limit the pool estimate as you can see)
PLOT IMAGE LINK
My code is basically this:
 #set margins
par(mar=c(10.8,0,1.3,1.3), mgp=c(3,0.2,0), tcl=-0.2)

#Forest plot
sav <- forest(res, 
              at=c(-3, -1, 0, 4, 8), 
              xlim=c(-30,11),
              xlab="", efac=c(1,4), 
              alim= c(-3, 2),
              textpos=c(-30,-4.7), 
              lty=c(1,1,0), 
              refline=NA,
              ilab=cbind(mean_PPP, SD_PPP, n_PPP, mean_CPP, SD_CPP, n_CPP, weights),
              ilab.xpos=c(-20.6,-18.6,-16.1,-14.1,-12,-10,-8.8),
              ilab.pos=2,
              cex=0.78, 
              header=c("Study","IV, Random, 95% CI"), 
              mlab="")

#add RoB region
pos  <- seq(sav$xlim[2]-5.5,sav$xlim[2]-0.5,length=6)
text(pos, k+2, c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), font=2)

Here i present the code for the creation of the model in case someone wants to play around with it
###create the data ser
library(tibble)

# Create 

    the dataframe
    LOS <- tribble(
      ~study,              ~Q2_PPP, ~Q1_PPP, ~Q3_PPP, ~n_PPP, ~Q2_CPP, ~Q1_CPP, ~Q3_CPP, ~n_CPP, ~mean_PPP, ~SD_PPP, ~mean_CPP, ~SD_CPP,
      "New Study 1",       15,       13,      24,      15,     16,      13,      28,      23,     17.3,     9,       19,        11.9,
      "New Study 2",       20,       17,      33,      12,     19.7,    15.7,    32.7,    32,     23.3,    13.4,     22.7,      13.2,
      "New Study 3",       20,       11,      28,      37,     15,       7,       20,      59,     19.7,    13.1,     14,         9.9
    )
    
    # Print the dataframe
    print(LOS)
    dat <- LOS %>%
      mutate(
        rb.a = c("?", "?", "?"),
        rb.b = c("?", "?", "?"),
        rb.c = c("?", "?", "?"),
        rb.d = c("?", "?", "?"),
        rb.e = c("?", "?", "?"),
        rb.f = c("?", "?", "?")
      )
    
    #for the last 5 columns, turn the risk of bias items into factors with levels +, -, and ?
    dat[14:19] <- lapply(dat[14:19], factor, levels=c("+", "-", "?"))
    
    ### calculate mean difference and corresponding sampling variances (and use
    ### the 'slab' argument to store study labels as part of the data frame)
    dat <- escalc(measure = "MD", 
                  m1i = mean_PPP, sd1i = SD_PPP,
                  m2i = mean_CPP, sd2i = SD_CPP,
                  n1i = n_PPP, n2i = n_CPP,
                  data = dat, slab = study)
    
    res <- rma(yi, vi, data = dat, method = "REML", slab = dat$study)

I tryed using arguments xlim, alim, olim and atransf; which unfortunately transforms both the estimate value and the estimate region axis as well, so i cannot re-scale the polygon without changing the value of the estimate.

Essentially, uou need to increase 'xlim' to make more space for the annotations (and then adjust other arguments accordingly).

is there any way of transforming the estimate x-axis without transforming the estimates as well?

I am sorry but I don't understand your question.

I´m trying to set an argument to determine the range of the effect measure shown at the estimate graph region, given a constant horizontal length of this region.
For example, I want this forest plot to show MD values between -3:3 (showing arrows for estimates larger than this), but using arguments alim or range, only truncate the estimate region, without rescaling it; atransf argument, as well, distorts both the axis and the estimates them self. Moreover, they only do not clip larger estiamates, infringing the area for other elements
